# Can't find string resources from another project

Tags: java, android, resources

I have an Android project let's call it ***SimpleProject*** in that project I get strings in this way `getString(R.string.error)` I keep all my strings in the projects `/res/values/strings.xml`. Besides ***SimpleProject*** is not a library project. Now I add my ***SimpleProject*** `src` folder as a linked resource to another project lets call it ***TestProject*** and then I try to build my ***TestProject*** Eclipse give me error that he can't find `R.string.error`. What can I do to solve this problem ?

***EDITED:***

I think about following issue

If I change all my applications packages to the same for example `com.android.victor` in that case all R-s will be same `com.android.victor.R` and if I add one project to another it will not bring to that that R will not be found. Am I right ? and what problems can appear in this case ?

Comment: Aren't you suppose to link res/values/strings.xml as well?

Comment: That not help it still say `R cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: You know how it works right? It runs through xml files, creates a class called R in bin/classes directory and you use that directly or with "import <your package>.R" if you are in a sub package. So when you link those in eclipse several issues might occur, but it must be doable.

Comment: Do you want TestProject to be a test project (i.e. tests for SimpleProject) ?

Comment: @dtmilano yes but not only test for SimpleProject also for SimpleProject1, SimpleProject2, SimpleProject3 etc.

Comment: What if two or more projects define R.string.error?

Comment: @dtmilano I cant understand your question

Comment: I want TestProject to be a test project for SimpleProject and at the same time for SimpleProject1 for example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to change the order,
1.go to **Java Build Path**
2.go to **Order and Export** and move the **SimpleProject** reference to be above the **TestProject**  folders

Comment: As in TestProject /gen there is no path to R of SimpleProject

Comment: yes i know, i have been investigate this behavior, and am sorry to say i don't believe there is such option, the only thing i can think of  is to use function call and send that string from that